# How can i refer an exist textbox via string variable which contains the textbox object name?

Tags: c#, object, casting, reference, textbox

```
public void findspecific(int winnerx, int winnery) 
{
   string ineed = "tb" + winnerx + winnery;
   ineed.text = "Something"; // --> this line isn't work because "ineed" is a string.
}
```

all the textboxes name starts with "tb" and the winnerx and winnery
 numbers together locate that textbox where the winner is
 I cant use ineed.Text because its a string not a button reference. How can i refer to tb(x)(y) button with "ineed" string
 variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WinForms:

```
    public void findspecific(int winnerx, int winnery)
    {
        string ineed = "tb" + winnerx.ToString() + winnery.ToString();
        Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find(ineed, true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)matches[0];
            tb.Text = "Something";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ineed, "No Match Found!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Depending upon your naming convention, you may need to zero pad your numbers with `winnerx.ToString("00")` and `winnery.ToString("00")`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this code working, but solved my problem :) Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this.

```
public void findspecific(int winnerx, int winnery) 
{
    string ineed = "tb" + winnerx + winnery;
    if ( anyButton.Name.Equals(indeed))   //
    {
         anyButton.Text = "Something";
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggested code does not provide the way to find a textbox by name

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly can you show me how its not provide a way to find. Where exactly the problem is ?. Which line ? You must be more specific why its not working?

Answer (score -2):

I'm fairly new to WPF, but something tells me you cannot do this. The TEXTBOX is a resource and it's assigned a resource ID, making it a CONST. In my project, I have had to encapsulate text assignments by parsing the string and using IF statements to update the appropriate TEXTBOX.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx

Comment: Follow Dmitry's link above. That's what I used but it says it better than I did